# Writing a RewriteRule based on X-Forwarded-Host

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite, http-headers

I have an Apache webserver behind a load balancer which proxies request to Apache and have problem regarding configuring directories.

Here is my scenario:

1. Upper Load Balancer proxies request to Apache with adding original Hostname in `X-Forwarded-Host`.
2. I should decide which directory to serve based on `X-Forwarded-Host` header value.
3. Incoming requests have `X-Forwarded-Host` headers like:
   `test1.example.com`
   `test2.example.com`
   `test3.example.com`
4. Here is my desired behavior:
   Each request must be served from: 
   `%{DocumentRoot}/test1/`
   `%{DocumentRoot}/test2/`
   `%{DocumentRoot}/test3/`
5. I wrote something like this, but it needs to be corrected:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host}" "^[^.]*"
RewriteRule "^(.*)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1" [L]
```

Any help on how to write Rewrite Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your `RewriteCond` pattern in parenthesis, like this:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host}" "^([^.]*)"
RewriteRule "^(.*)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1" [L]
```